# How to pin the popup in Microsoft Edge extensions

Tags: microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-extension

I want to create a popup and pin it similar to what the History/Favs button does. How would I do that? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use browserAction.onClicked (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/browserAction/onClicked) API to inject an IFRAME onto the webpage. Using z-index CSS property you could make it float on top of the actual page content. This will make the popup stay on the page as if it were pinned.